# getting random econnrefused in my webservices

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I created some webservices following all the google cloud functions docs consuming a second generation MySQL DB.
Everything run smoothly but I'm getting random "Econnrefused" errors:

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED /cloudsql/calculator-226400:us-central1:vanessasqlus at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1191:14) -------------------- at Protocol._enqueue (/srv/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48) at Protocol.handshake (/srv/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23) at PoolConnection.connect (/srv/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:118:18) at Pool.getConnection (/srv/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16) at Pool.query (/srv/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:202:8) at Object.get_user (/srv/request_post/user.js:15:15) at exports.landing_ws (/srv/index.js:84:18) at /worker/worker.js:783:7 at /worker/worker.js:766:11 at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7) errno: 'ECONNREFUSED', code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '/cloudsql/calculator-226400:us-central1:vanessasqlus', fatal: true }
```

I migrated everything o U.S. and I'm still getting random connection errors.
This is my connection String:

```
const connectionName =
    process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME || 'calculator-226400:us-central1:vanessasqlus';
const dbUser = process.env.SQL_USER || '*';
const dbPassword = process.env.SQL_PASSWORD || '*';
const dbName = process.env.SQL_NAME || '*';

let mysqlConfig = {
    connectionLimit: 1,
    user: dbUser,
    password: dbPassword,
    database: dbName,
};
...
if (!mysqlPool) {
        mysqlPool = mysql.createPool(mysqlConfig);
    }
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
mysqlConfig.socketPath = `/cloudsql/${connectionName}`;
}
```

Comment: UPDATE:
I wasn't closing my functions properly. because of the Async methods

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Functions provides a Unix socket at `/cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>` that can be used to connect to a Cloud SQL instance. You need to specify this requirement in your config:

```
mysqlConfig.socketPath = `/cloudsql/${connectionName}`;
```

If you are connecting cross region or cross project, there are some additional steps you need to follow, but you can find those [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/sql#setting_up_cloud_sql).

Comment: I updated the code for my question.
that was included in my code

Comment: Do you also have `process.env.NODE_ENV` equal to 'production'? Is the function in the same region and project at the Cloud SQL database?

Comment: ok, I removed the condition and now it's just:

mysqlConfig.socketPath = `/cloudsql/${connectionName}`;

Comment: Are you still receiving the same error? Are you testing deployed or locally (running locally won't grant you access to the unix socket)?

Comment: It was a problem in the way I closed the functions when it is Async. Thanks anyways